# Double pointer to a 1D array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc

Please bear with me as I've got little to no idea what I'm talking about. I'm trying to read the data (excluding the header) from a PGM file. I've got a function (read_data) which accepts  accepts a double pointer (char** data) as a parameter.

Within the function, I'm able to put the data into an array (arr) but my problem is assigning that pointer (**data) to that array. Here is my code thus far:

```
read_data(char* file, char** data) {
FILE *fp = fopen(file, "rb");
char type[3], dump;
int i =0, data_length;
int w, h; // width & height

fgets(type, sizeof(type), fp);
fscanf(fp, "%d", &w);
fscanf(fp, "%d", &h);

if (strcmp(type, "P5 ")) { 
    data_length = w * h;
    }
else { 
    data_length = (w * h) * 3;
    } // this is to work out the size of the array (how many bits of data are in the    file)

char arr[data_length];

while ((dump = fgetc(fp)) != '\n'); // just to skip the header

for (i; i < data_length; i++) {
arr[i] = fgetc(fp);
}

data = &arr; // <--- The problem

fclose(fp);

return data_length;

}

main () {
int data_length;
char **data = malloc(sizeof(int*)*data_length);

read_data("file.pgm",data);

}
```

Hope this is readable.  Thanks.

Comment: What is `image_data`? Where is it declared? Why do you think you can assign to an array? Arrays are non-modifiable l-values, you can't assign to an array.

Answer (score 2):

You are combining two different problems: file I/O and pointer handling. Since the real problem is the pointer handling, let's use a simpler example. First, a function that can create and fill an array of `char`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void foo()
{
  char arr[6];
  strcpy(arr, "hello");
  printf("%s\n", arr);
}
```

So far, so good. (And from here on I'll leave out the `#include` directives.) But this is an array on the stack, so it turns back into wilderness when control passes out of the function. We want dynamic allocation, on the heap:

```
void foo()
{
  char *arr = malloc(6*sizeof(char));
  strcpy(arr, "hello");
  printf("%s\n", arr);
}
```

(**Note:** in your question you declare the array outside the function, but that means that you must do so without knowing what length it should be, which doesn't seem to be what you intend. This is a cleaner approach, and if you really want to declare the array outside, you can do that with only slight alteration.)

Now about the pointer. It's easy to assign the address of this array (which is the value assigned to `arr`) to another pointer:

```
char *p;
p = arr;
```

but we don't want to assign that value to some local pointer variable in the function; we want to assign it to a pointer value back in the scope of the code *calling* the function. The way to do that with an ordinary variable is by use of a pointer to that variable:

```
void bar(int *k)
{
  *k = 5;
}

...
int n;
bar(&n);
...
```

So we do the same with this pointer variable:

```
void foo(char **p)
{
  char *arr = malloc(6*sizeof(char));
  strcpy(arr, "hello");
  *p = arr;
}

int main()
{
  char *z;
  foo(&z);
  printf("%s\n", z);
}
```

(We could even do away with `arr`, but let's take things slowly.)

Once this is clear, you can splice it to the code that handles file I/O. Remember, always develop new functionality in isolation.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
int n = 0;

while(condition)
    nextchar = fgetc(filepointer);
    (*image_data)[n]= nextchar;
    // or (*data)[n]= nextchar;
    n++;
```